# insertListItem(index, text) Wrong Index

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to replace text into a Docs template and save it as a .pdf.  I am mostly successful, but I am having one problem.  I'd like for the script to search for a text in the template, replace the text with provided text, using bullets.  It will ignore any extra \n that may have been placed into the text.  Here is an example text:

```
Today was a good day.
Tomorrow will be a good day.

Yesterday was a decent day.
```

In my document, I would like the text to replace `_text_` in a line: `Comments: _text_`.  Ultimately, what should print out is the following:

```
Comments:
- Today was a good day.
- Tomorrow will be a good day.
- Yesteday was a decent day.
```

This is the code that I have so far, but it is not working too well.  If anyone could offer any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
var listr = "";
var trunc = text.split("\n"); \\ where text is to be placed into the template
var index = b.findText("_text_").getStartOffset(); \\ var b is getBody()
for (var j = (trunc.length - 1); j >= 0; j--)
  if(!trunc[j].equals("")) b.insertListItem(index, trunc[j]);
b.replaceText("_text_", "");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  I am having the hardest time understanding the concept of the indexes in Google Docs.  Thank you.

---

Hello.  Just wanted to let you know how I have ended up implementing this:

```
var trunc = text.split("\n"); \\where text is to be placed into the template
var index = b.getChildIndex(b.findText("foo").getElement().getParent()) + 1;
for (var j = (trunc.length - 1); j >= 0; j--)
  if (trunc[j] != "") b.insertListItem(index, trunc[j]);
```

Hope that helps.  It pushes the elements back on to each other backwards.

Comment: Good Question, can you share any other resources you've found?

Comment: @JasonK Please see edits above for how I've implemented this.  There seems to be little documentation and I am an amateur coder, at best.  It took me sometime to figure this out.  Your code helped me quite a bit, so thank you. [=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well this crude code seems to insert at the beginning of the PARAGRAPH containing the TEXT, which appears to be a separate child element. Probably this particular code will only work if the text is not inside a sub-table, sub-list, etc... but maybe it will help.

```
var element = DocumentApp.create('newDoc').getBody()
  .appendListItem('testing').copy();
var index = b.getChildIndex(
  b.findText('_text_').getElement().getParent().asParagraph() );
b.insertListItem(index, element);
```

I've had a long day maybe I can improve it later, mostly what I think was missing was the getChildIndex() function. Also using the newDoc the insertListItem() had some weird "Element must be detached." message until I used .copy() so mental note there.